# Help me diagnose these print problems?

Tags: 3d-models, simplify3d

I produced a cube model (XYZ) using a printer to test its capabilities. Could someone offer guidance concerning the issues visible in the image?. [image]

Printer Used : Createbot F430
Slicer Used: Simplify 3D
[image: Slicer Settings]

[image]

Comment: You haven't provided any information about your printer. These artifacts look like oozing during retract or unretract due to an excessively slow retract/unretract speed, but might also be related to misconfigured or lack of pressure advance/linear advance.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the question. Is my Retract Distance too small ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These artifacts look like oozing during retract or unretract due to an excessively slow retract/unretract speed, but might also be related to misconfigured or lack of pressure advance/linear advance.

Based on the settings info you added to the question, I think this is a very plausible explanation.

The "extra restart distance" setting is probably the primary culprit. This is an **extremely misguided feature** and, with the configured value, is spewing out enough plastic to fill a whole 1.25 mm worth of linear movement (at typical layer height and line width). All this is ending up in one place as a blob. Turn that off (set it to zero) and the problem will almost surely go away. There is never a legitimate reason to extrude a fixed excess amount of plastic after each unretract, and doing so will cause **catastrophic nozzle collisions** dependent on your model geometry.

Beyond that, 2.0 mm is a very long retract distance for a direct drive, which I believe this machine has, and 15 mm/s is very slow retraction. Those combined make it take at least 1/7 of a second dwelling in place during retract/unretract, which could also ooze material. 0.3-0.8 mm is the usual reasonable range of lengths for direct drive, and 30 mm/s (1800 mm/min) or so a reasonable speed. Play with these, but set it back up closer to where you had it if you get stringing or other problems.

The coasting setting of 2 mm is really, really dubious too. Coasting is a hack to make up for printers with extremely outdated/bad firmware by underextruding. This doesn't seem to be the *cause* of your bulges, but it could be making them more noticeable by contrast between slightly over-extruded (from oozing) and severely underextruded lines juxtaposed. Coasting should always be off.

Assuming your printer has it (I would hope so at that price, but sometimes pricy printers are running really old firmware), you should also make sure linear advance is enabled and calibrated. This solves the problem that coasting was trying to solve, but does it in a way that's actually accurate and still extrudes the correct total amount of material, just modulating pressure up and down as it does so that it flows in the right places.

TL;DR: Set extra restart distance to 0, coasting to off, and maybe speed up and reduce the length for your retractions.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I'll conduct additional test prints with the settings recommended and observe the outcomes